# Modulus of vectors squared

Tags: vectors

Recently, I saw someone write:
$|OC - OB|^2 = |OC^2 - 2OC\cdot OB + OB^2|$ where $OC$ and $OB$ are both vectors.

I was wondering if this is the same thing or not?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Blondie:  Is my edit correct?

Comment: @EmilioNovati Yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) and the properties of the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition):

$$
\begin{align}
|OC-OB|^2 & = (OC-OB)\cdot (OC-OB) \\
& = OC \cdot OC - OC \cdot OB - OB \cdot OC + OB \cdot OB \\
& = |OC|^2 - 2\; OC \cdot OB + |OB|^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you! I see where it comes from now

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

See the figure:

[image]

$
\vec {AB}-\vec{AC}=\vec {BC}
$ is the side of the triangle $ABC$ opposite to the angle $A$, so the identity 
$$
|\vec AB-\vec AC|^2=|\vec AB|^2 -2\vec{AB}\cdot \vec{AC}+|\vec AC|^2
$$

is the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) applied to the triangle $ABC$, with the [geometric interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) of the dot product. (Note that the use of the modulus is wrong in OP).

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot of sense now

Answer (score 0):

Let's go from the basics. Take $OC=\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i, \ \ OB=\sum_{i=1}^nb_ix_i$ where $\{x_i\}$ form the orthogonal basis of the space.
$$OC-OB=\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-b_i)x_i\\\implies |OC-OB|^2=(\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-b_i))^2$$
Now  $$OC^2-2OC\cdot OB+OB^2\\=\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2-2\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i+\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2\\=(\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-b_i))^2$$